# How to fit text and its appropriate size within resizable div..?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, resize, font-size

I have a `resizable` div with some text. While resize the div, the last line text goes out of the div. How to make fit all the text within the `resizable` div by maintaining its appropriate font size.?

**Sample code**

```
resize: function(e, ui) 
{
    var newDiagonal = getContentDiagonal();
    var ratio = newDiagonal / initDiagonal;

    $("#content").css("font-size", initFontSize + ratio * 3);
}
```

**Below image shows the problem**

[image]

Code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/ptd32doy/) in Jsfiddle..!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple actually. I saw in your fiddle that you did the following:

```
#content { font-size: 16; overflow: hidden; }
```

Instead of applying the overflow to your css for #content, I applied the following and it worked for both the widget header and content:

```
#resizeable { width: 150px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden; }
```

Just to note in order for overflow to work properly you must have a block level element which by default the div element already is and you must also specify a height value which you have. did this answer your question?

Comment: @ Ethan Ettleman...  How to make font fixed inside the div..? I don't want to make hide the overflowed text. Can you please able to achieve..